# Log a Windows user into a remote computer

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here is what I am doing: 
I have several servers that are used to run a piece of software. The software is started using a scheduled task. I can have up to three instances of the software running using three scheduled tasks, and three logged in users. Currently I am using a separate program running on two additional servers to make sure these two additional users are logged in, the scheduled task will not run if the user is not logged in.  This separate program uses a saved Remote Desktop Session to make sure the users are logged in.

Here is what I would like to do:
The RDP session needs a username/password to log the user in, this is stored separate from the RDP file. This is all getting very large and tedious to maintain. What I am looking for is a way to check if all the users are logged in, and if not log them in, without the separate RDP session files and separate username/password stored in the Credential Manager.

I have looked at a couple of ways that can get the user information from the server, but I have not found a good way to accomplish the logging in. It just seems like there should be a simple way to accomplish this. I am using VB.Net 2.0 with Windows 2003 servers.

Let me know if I am not clear on something.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Maybe a little more clarification: The second and third users need to simulate a user logging in from another machine and stay logged in so the main scheduled tasks can run.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

You would write a program using this function that would run before your current scheduled tasks.

Comment: This doesn't quiet work the way I need it too. I can get it to successfully to log in, but the new user either does not show up or is logged out and it will need to stay logged in for the scheduled task to run.

Comment: I don't really understand why you need the user logged in when you can tell the Task Scheduler what user to use when running the task.

Comment: Because the main application uses screen capture, each user needs to have their own session as to not cause issues with each other. I guess I should have explained that better...sorry.

Comment: Mind if I ask the purpose of the screen-capture software?  I can't envision what's going on here capture a screen that essentially has no human input...?

Comment: Without going into a huge, long explanation it is used to get data from an outside computer system. I have a VB program that starts a telenet application. This logs into a outside system to gather data. (All with the clients permission.) The entire process is automated, but needs to act like a person sitting at the terminal. The screen capture is part of how I gather the data.

Comment: hmmm.. I don't know off the top of my head.  Mebe try something like Autohotkey.